# Cache Redis on Azure

Tags: microsoft-azure

Contratei o serviço de cache **Azure Cache Redis**, porém para importar o database atual tive que migra-lo para `Premium P1`, após importar tentei voltar para o `C0`, impossível, o **Azure Cache Redis** só faz *upscale* nunca *downscale*.

Preciso criar o meu database, mas no `C3` da timeout. Por padrão creio que ele rodaria em um `B2`, porém o processo de criação do database é pesado e complexo.
Então como conseguir importar ou gerar o database inicial se o scaling só é pra cima?

Será que se eu fizer, 2 conexões, um com meu servidor de redis atual e outro no azure, e fizer um select e depois um set no azure, será rapido? São 90mil *keys* pra gerar, cada uma bem grandinha.

Informações sobre os planos Redis Azure
https://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/pricing/details/cache/

Pedido para poder fazer *downscale* no serviço do Redis no issue do Azure
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169382-cache/suggestions/10560624-smaller-premium-redis-instances

Comment: O link sobre "pedido de downscale" não deve estar correto. Os assunto são diferentes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Infelizmente o serviço Cache Redis (Paas) do Azure ainda possui algumas limitações como:

- Importar somente camada premium;
- Impossível fazer downgrade da camada, após colocar em um Premium para importação, ficará preso sempre neste.

Minha solução foi, contratar uma VM com windows e instalar o Redis Cache (poderia ser uma VM linux também) e assim o custo ficou menor e com desempenho superior a Premium P1.

Answer (score -1):

Eu imagino que não esteja conseguindo fazer o *downscaling* pois, após carregar 90K keys, apenas alguns planos suportem estocar todos esses dados.

Não sei o tamanho da sua massa de dados, mas, por exemplo, a `C0` suporta apenas 250MB de cache - esse tamanho é diretamente proporcional à sua massa de dados, mas a relação não é 1 para 1.

Sobre o *timeout*, se puder compartilhar o trecho do seu código que está suando para fazer a migraça, posso tentar ajudar a identificar pontos de melhoria, mas, de qualquer forma, eu recomendo a seguir os seguintes passos:

1. Crie seu serviço de Azure Redis Cache em um plano que seja interessante para seu negócio - no seu caso, provavelmente no `B2`;
2. Provisione uma VM no mesmo *DataCenter* - se possível no mesmo Resource Group - do seu serviço de cache;
3. Copie seu backup para essa VM e faça a importação dos dados a partir de lá.
4. Após a importação finalizar, exclua a VM.

Isso fará que vc realize a importação via "rede local", tornando menor a change de obter timeout ou perda de pacotes.

Comment: 90k não da nem 180mb

Comment: 180mb de dados exportados. Se somar as redundâncias, mais índices, etc, pode sim passar dos 250mb.

Comment: até concordo mas o plano q testei foi de c3 da mais de 2gb

Comment: Sim, mas isso me refiro a não conseguir fazer o downscale

Comment: mas não era esse o problema, de acordo com o manual do Azure o Redis ainda não possui downscale.